Is there a way to hide the google password prompt when creating a password input field?
I am working on a company Intranet page where I want the user to reauthenticate before viewing the page as it contains sensitive data.  I don't want the user to be able to use passwords or passkeys stored in their google account because the computers are shared.  Is there a way to prevent the google prompt from displaying?  I have tried setting autocomplete to off as well as new-password on the input field but still the prompt still displays.

